# Stored procedure assíncrona

Tags: c#, asp.net, mvc

Ao tentar executar procedure assincronamente

```
public async Task<ActionResult> Index()
    {
        Stopwatch watch = new Stopwatch();
        watch.Start();
        ContentManagement service = new ContentManagement();
        var contentTask = service.MesesAsync();
        var content = await contentTask;
        watch.Stop();                    
        ViewBag.WatchMilliseconds = watch.ElapsedMilliseconds;
        return View("Index");
     }

public async Task<List<SP_MESES_BUSCA_Result>> MesesAsync()
    {
        var ListarMes = await db.SP_MESES_BUSCA().ToList();
        return ListarMes;
    }
```

Retorna o erro:

> Cannot await 'System.Collections.Generic.List'

Answer (score 2):

O `await` em seu método `MesesAsync()` está esperando uma instrução assíncrona.

Basta alterar o `ToList()` para `ToListAsync()` que irá funcionar.

Seu código ficará assim;

```
public async Task<List<SP_MESES_BUSCA_Result>> MesesAsync()
    {
        var ListarMes = await db.SP_MESES_BUSCA().ToListAsync();
        return ListarMes;
    }
```

Comment: Aparece esse erro agora "does not contain a definition for 'ToListAsync' and the best extension method overload 'QueryableExtensions.ToListAsync(IQueryable)'"

caso coloque ".AsQueryable() o erro some mais na hora de executar aparece Only sources that implement IDbAsyncEnumerable can be used for Entity Framework asynchronous operations. For more details see "

Comment: Adicione está referência ao seu projeto: `using System.Data.Entity;`

Comment: Já estou utilizando, se eu fizer com uma tabela funciona, agora com a procedure da esses erros.

Comment: Veja [este tutorial](http://www.asp.net/mvc/overview/getting-started/getting-started-with-ef-using-mvc/async-and-stored-procedures-with-the-entity-framework-in-an-asp-net-mvc-application)